# Is granting Fey Ancestry to a fey creature unbalancing?

Tags: dnd-5e, house-rules, familiars, racial-traits

Elves and half-elves have the fey ancestry racial trait; however, I have noticed that the fey creatures do not have the same trait. It seems illogical that fey would not have the benefits of Fey Ancestry.

In my current campaign, I have a Half-elf warlock that has taken a sprite familiar. Would it be unbalancing to give the sprite familiar the traits of fey ancestry (adv against charm and immunity to magical sleep)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**The value of Fey Ancestry is roughly half a stat score** <sup>1</sup>, which will hardly unbalance anything.

In particular, adding that to a **friendly creature** is even less harmful. Giving it to a foe *might* increase its CR (probably won't as well), and certainly will make the encounter harder for low level parties, where it's usual for the Spellcaster to rely on *sleep* as their major utility spell. For friendly creatures though, how often will **the familiar** be targeted/affected by *sleep* or charms? My experience says: seldom. And I frequently put spellcasters against my parties.

---

<sup>1</sup> There is a [reddit guide on homebrew races](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ViqLSEN67mmd2Lo_OJ-H5YX0fccsfI97kFaqx7V1Dmw/pub) (link to google docs) that ranks racial features using an ability score as the unity (e.g., +1 Dex = 1 point). From my experience, this guide was well received and I use it commonly to get feedback for my own homebrew races (although I don't use it to **design** them). There are other guides that do the same thing, e.g. [this one](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vq1kz6PRAbw5LHy6amH-bNb4OuB8DBXL1RsZROt03Sc/edit#gid=0) (link to google docs). This one handles different ASI better (e.g. +2/+2 is as good as human +1 for everyone, which is a net +6). Both of them rank the Fey Ancestry feature as half a stat, as I described. That's my personal value for it, as well. Since the time this answer was posted, [the guide has been updated](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XQ9shwsH5tu2s4Nt4J2Lie-pY4_G8CYhjB-yuJ7FlTk/edit#gid=1880237047). The conclusion of the answer did not change, though.

Comment: Worth noting the second link now lists fey ancestry with a score of 2...

Comment: @IsaacReefman Yeah, but a +1 ASI there has a score of 4 :P - so Fey Ancestry is consistently half a +1 ASI

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't looking at the decimal version - a later sheet, same info, basically everything is divided by 4. So the same. Which I would have known if I'd read the guide...

Comment: It has always bothered me that PC races have abilities that the monster entries do not... such as Fury of the Small... seems like lazy design to me.

Comment: Why bother adding those sorts of things to a character who's only going to show up for one fight before dying? It just adds word count to the book and a bit of added mental complexity to the encounter, for minimal return.

Comment: @nick012000 Actually, the NPCs in the back of the MM have no racial anything attached, the idea is that you as the DM add them which adds diversity (buzz word) and depth to the encounter. It should feel different to fight a group of elves rather than a group of goblins.

Comment: I just want to add that now exists a [new guide](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XQ9shwsH5tu2s4Nt4J2Lie-pY4_G8CYhjB-yuJ7FlTk/edit) about homebrew races which is based on the previous guide but with some tweaks and the new races.

Comment: @Enderluck thanks, I have added it to the answer. Although I don't have the time to carefully read and analyze it right now, it seems it doesn't affect the current answer, so no need for me to edit it :)

Comment: This seems to be completely unrelated to the topic in question, so I suggest either discussing it in the chat or through voting in the linked question.

Answer (score 5):

No. These are two very minor traits, which aren't likely to come up very often. Granting them to a creature won't break anything and it seems thematic enough to give them to a sprite.